# Remove dynamically appended HTML from DOM with ng-click. AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, append, directive

I built a directive that dynamically appends html. I used the $compile service to add my ng-click function to the scope so I can remove items from my collection, however, it does not remove it from the DOM. It only removes it from the collection. Any thoughts on how to remove an individual item from the collection and have it update the DOM accordingly?

Here is my code:

```
app.directive('appendCategory', function(){
 return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: function($scope, $http, $compile, $filter){
        $scope.addedCategories = [];
        $scope.categoryList = "";

        $http.get('/api/categories/all-categories').success(function(response){
            $scope.categories = response.map(function(category){
                return {
                    name: category.name
                }
            })
        })

        $scope.onSelect = function ($item) {
            $scope.nameObject = [$item.name];
            $scope.addedCategories.push($scope.nameObject);
        };

        $scope.addCategory = function(){
            var myElement = angular.element(document.querySelector('#appended'));
            $scope.categoryList = ("<span class='label label-default'>" + $scope.selectedCategory + "<i class='fa fa-times' ng-click='removeCategory()'></i></span>");
            var compiled = $compile($scope.categoryList)($scope);
            myElement.append(compiled);

            $scope.addedCategories.push({category: $scope.categoryList && $scope.selectedCategory, deleted:false});
            console.log($scope.addedCategories);
            $scope.selectedCategory = "";
        }

        $scope.removeCategory = function(index){
            $scope.addedCategories.splice(index,1);
            console.log($scope.addedCategories);
        }
    },
    templateUrl: '/category/category.html'
 }
})
```

Mark-Up: It is appended here.

```
 <div class="margin-top-1" id="appended"></div>
```

Comment: Your markup is important.  And without exception, `$compile` should NOT occur in controllers, only in directives.  And I suspect that all of the compilation code could be replaced with a proper `ng-repeat` implementation.

Comment: this is a directive, just not using a link function

Comment: Direct DOM manipulation is rarely a good idea in Angular for exactly this reason: you have to jump through a lot of extra hoops to do what the framework would do for you automatically.  If you just ng-repeat over scope.categories you won't have to do all this $compile stuff (and the data binding would remove DOM elements for you when you remove them from the collection.)

Comment: Okay that makes a lot of sense. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Schw2iizer yes, it is a directive, but you're performing all of this DOM manipulation logic in the controller hook, which is an AngularJS code smell.

Comment: @David L. Yes, you're right. Thanks a lot for helping me recognize that. I don't want the smell ;). Using it as an ng-repeat instead. I made it way too complicated.

Comment: @Schw2iizer no problem, happy to help!